# Changing save-path of StreamWriter?

Tags: c#

I built a really simple code as I am a beginner to coding,
so would anyone mind helping me change the save-directory of my code?
Here it is:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
            objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("ETS2AUFTRAGSLISTE.txt", true);

            objWriter.Write("Fahrer: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine();
            objWriter.WriteLine(tbDriver.Text);
            objWriter.Write("Fahrzeug: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine();
            objWriter.WriteLine(tbVeh.Text);
            objWriter.Write("Uhrzeit von: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine();
            objWriter.WriteLine(tbTimeVON.Text);
            objWriter.Write("bis: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine();
            objWriter.WriteLine(tbTimeBIS.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Hochgeladen!");

        }
    }
}
```

Where and how do I add a directory path change?
I have been trying for hours and couldnt really find a video that explains it.

Comment: "couldnt really find a video that explains it" -- yeesh, you damn kids. Not everything has to be on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\TestFolder1\test1\ETS2AUFTRAGSLISTE.txt", true);
```

Change the path like the above...